# Startindex cannot be less than zero showing instead of 404 page

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco

I have an Umbraco 4.11.10 site, and am having a huge problem with how it's handling 404 errors. It should give me a 'not found' page, but instead is giving me this error. I don't have any advanced plugins installed, and I can verify it's doing it on at least one other site I know of.

Any help would be massively appreciated, I'm really stuck on this and am all out of ideas.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> StartIndex cannot be less than zero. Parameter name: startIndex
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: StartIndex
>   cannot be less than zero. Parameter name: startIndex
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentOutOfRangeException: StartIndex cannot be less than zero.
>   Parameter name: startIndex]
>   System.String.InternalSubStringWithChecks(Int32 startIndex, Int32
>   length, Boolean fAlwaysCopy) +10698829
>   System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex) +12
>   AutoFolders.NotFoundHandler.Execute(String url) +538
>   Umbraco.Web.Routing.LookupByNotFoundHandlers.HandlePageNotFound(PublishedContentRequest
>   docRequest) +1148
>   Umbraco.Web.Routing.LookupByNotFoundHandlers.TrySetDocument(PublishedContentRequest
>   docRequest) +10
>   Umbraco.Web.Routing.PublishedContentRequestBuilder.b_*1e(IPublishedContentLookup
>   lookup) +15    System.Linq.Enumerable.Any(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2
>   predicate) +146
>
>   Umbraco.Web.Routing.PublishedContentRequestBuilder.LookupDocument1()
>   +198    Umbraco.Web.Routing.PublishedContentRequestBuilder.LookupDocument()
>   +195    Umbraco.Web.Routing.PublishedContentRequest.ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, UmbracoContext umbracoContext, Action`1 onSuccess) +139
>
>   Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule.ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext)
>   +339    Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule.b*_7(Object sender, EventArgs e) +80
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +136    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69

Comment: Can you try without the AutoFolders package installed?

Comment: Thanks Emil. the autofolders is causing the issue, specifically it adds a line to the 404handlers config file:
 <notFound assembly="AutoFolders" type="NotFoundHandler"/>

If I remove this line the 404 behaves correctly, but I am not sure if removing it will break something else with the autofolders.

Comment: I've done the same as I was having the issue. Please keep in touch if you have found an issue with AutoFolders. I'll do the same.